# How to import html file as template in typescript vue js project as module to use same html file in more than a component?

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to load external html file in to Vuejs project in typescript language but typescript compiler gives me issue as below

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                    3:51:57 PM
 error  in ./src/components/common/dynamic-render.html
```

I dont have webpack.config.js as this project is generated through vue-cli

I tried to load file with the help of `vue-template-loader  ts-loader` but still compiler throws same issue

Dashboard.vue

```
import WithRender from "./common/dynamic-render.html";

@WithRender
@Component
```

I am getting below error

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                    3:51:57 PM
 error  in ./src/components/common/dynamic-render.html

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you defined `shims-html.d.ts` as explained in [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-template-loader/)?

Comment: Yes I have defined types for html and css.